# Play Framework 2.1 IDE Setup

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm having trouble setting up the IDE for a new project in Play 2.1.0. I prefer netbeans and when I run

```
play netbeans
```

I get the following error:

```
[error] Not a valid command: netbeans
[error] Expected '/'
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: netbeans (similar: test, tags, streams)
[error] netbeans 
[error]         ^
```

Interestingly it also doesn't seem to work for Eclipse, but it does for Idea.

Comment: `$ play; eclipse with-source=true;` works fine for me with 2.1.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a dependency to use the Netbeans project generator.

> Play does not have native Netbeans project generation support at this
>   time. For now you can generate a Netbeans Scala project with the
>   [Netbeans SBT plugin](https://github.com/remeniuk/sbt-netbeans-plugin).

First edit the *plugins.sbt* file

```
resolvers += {
  "remeniuk repo" at "http://remeniuk.github.com/maven" 
}

libraryDependencies += {
  "org.netbeans" %% "sbt-netbeans-plugin" % "0.1.4"
}
```

Now run

```
$ play netbeans
```

Source: [Setting up your preferred IDE](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/IDE)